# Sidebar border indent

Tags: html, css

On my site I have added a border-left to the sidebar. The issue I have is that this border is very close to the text to the left of it and I would like to move the border slightly to the right. I have tried various ways of doing this, but all were unsuccessful.

```
.blog-sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks chris. Any thoughts on how that can be added to the border in the code above? Sorry, I'm a novice at this.

Comment: Well it would be easier to tell you exactly if you could provide some more of your css code and markup, or perhaps a link to your site.

Comment: provide some more code or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a margin on the left-hand side? For example:

```
.blog-sidebar {
width: 250px;
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

That should give you some space between the border and the content on the left.

For reference, see the CSS box model

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Thanks, but that had no effect unfortunately